# Failed to install pyang

Tags: python, ietf-netmod-yang, yang

I'm trying to install pyang by pip install pyang command and I got this error :
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/pyang/

Thank you.

Comment: Your post is difficult to decipher, you need to learn how to use the formatting tools to make it easier for people to help you. re-wrote your post to make it look like it should then took a screen shot and deleted it so that you can see what your posts need to look like: https://i.imgur.com/fGMkmSG.png

Comment: you can provide your os version, python version etc. especially, error log, not just one line error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there may be a proxy issue. you can try downloading the whl file from:

`https://pypi.org/project/pyang/#files`
currently the link is [this](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/22/16c98564086f4f5901b7e8d886ad928ce6eceb577b3504edc333762df92f/pyang-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl)
after that open terminal and go to the whl file directory and type:

`pip install yourpackagename.whl`

and it's done.